# Do jpackage created apps have more security constraints on Windows?

Tags: java, windows-10, jpackage

I have a jpackage-created application (OpenJDK 20.0.2) I deliver to macOS, Linux, and Windows.  It works on all 3.  I added an 'update' feature, whereby the application checks a server for an updated main jar (e.g. app.jar) and, if one exists, downloads it into a user directory (e.g. $HOME/app/updates/app.jar) and makes a copy of the app's installer App.cfg file, replacing the classpath for the app.jar with where the new one is located, and puts the updated cfg file into the appropriate place for the platform.  E.g. on Linux it puts the cfg file into $HOME/.app/, on macOS, it puts it in $HOME/Library/Application Support/app/, and on Windows 10, it puts it into $HOME/AppData/roaming/app/.

On macOS and on Linux, everything works as expected - ie the application downloads a new jar and, the next time the application is started, it uses that new jar.  But on Windows, all I get is a small dialog that says "Failed to launch JVM".  If I copy the original app.jar (the one put in C:\Program Files\App\app\ to the directory where the updated app.jar was downloaded, the application starts again.  If I do the reverse (putting my update app.jar into the installation directory), I see the "Failed to launch JVM" dialog.  The only guess I have is that in Windows, there is some sort of fingerprinting of the jars that prevents changed ones from executing?

Is that, indeed, the case?  If not, is there a way to debug this situation?  I.e. is there some additional config info or environment variable I can provide to see more detailed information on why the application failed to launch the JVM?

Any help appreciated.

P.S.  Note: the ability to create a local CFG file wasn't added until JDK 19.  See [this issue](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8250950) for details.

Comment: How are you replacing the classpath?  Have you tried launching the program on the command line?  Side note:  Linux files should be in $HOME/.local/share/app.  (Or more formally, $XDG_DATA_HOME/app, and if XDG_DATA_HOME is undefined or its value is not an absolute path, fall back to using $HOME/.local/share/app.)

Comment: @VGR package-installed applications have an Application.cfg file that's in the installation directory.  That file has a listing of all the jar files that constitute the application - e.g.: under the [Application] section, you'd see lines like:
"app.classpath=$APPDIR/app.jar" and the jpackage provided launcher substitutes the variable $APPDIR with the actual installation directory.  When I make a local copy of the cfg file, I modify this line to point to the updated app.jar that the application downloaded.

Comment: So you’re overwriting a file in the installation tree?  I suspect the application may not have permission to do that.

Comment: @VGR - no, I'm not overwriting a file in the installation tree.  Starting with JDK 19, you're allowed to have a local copy of the file and the jpackage launcher will look there to see if there's one to override the default installation-tree based cfg file.

But I think you may have solved the problem for me anyway - why didn't I think of trying it on the command-line as you suggest???  I get a NullPointerException in my app code when I do it from the command-line!  Still not sure why I get a "Failed to launch JVM".  I will check if fixing the app bug solves the above. THANKS either way!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is "no".  It turns out (thanks to @VGR for suggesting I run the app from the command-line), that my application, in its main() function caught a NullPointerException and in its catch block wrote a log message and then did a System.exit(-1) to indicate the application ended abnormally.

The message the application wrapper put up "Failed to launch JVM" is simply wrong and misleading.: it DID NOT fail to launch the JVM - the JVM got launched and my application ran, and simply exited with a -1 exit code.  I will try to create a simple use case and file a bug report with OpenJDK.

Sorry for kind of wasting people's time.